# Conditionally replacing values without it affecting the original column conditional statement is based on

Tags: r, conditional-statements

everyone.  I have figured out how to replace values in R based on satisfying some condition in another column in a dataframe.  However, the code I wrote seems to apply the conditional statement to the original column I have based the condition on.  Basically, I want values to be replaced in all columns in the dataframe *except* for the column I used to make the rule/condition.

Here is sample data (df):

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
0   0   0   0   0   Y   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   Y   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   Y   0   0   Y   0   Y
0   0   Y   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   Y   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   Y
0   0   0   0   0   0   Y   0
```

I wanted the following to be satisfied for each row: if value in column C6 is "Y", I wanted the values in the rest of the columns to be converted in 0s.

```
df[df$C6 == "Y",] = 0      # Most common code I found on SO to accomplish this
```

When I execute the above line of code, it also applies this rule to column C6 (changes a "Y" in C6 to 0).  I do not want this--I want to keep values in C6 as they were while doing the replacements in the other columns.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: The code you have applies the results to all columns. Use `df[df$C6 == "Y",-which(names(df) == "C6")] = 0`

Comment: Thank you, @Alex!  It sounds like you and thelatemail (below) had come to the same conclusion (although you use -which() while thelatemail uses -match()).  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative indexing on the column selection:

```
df[df$C6 == "Y", -match("C6",names(df))] <- 0

#   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
#1   0  0  0  0  0  Y  0  0
#2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  Y
#3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  Y
#4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  Y
#5   0  0  Y  0  0  0  0  Y
#6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  Y
#7   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  Y
#8   0  0  0  0  0  Y  0  0
# ....
```

Comment: Thank you, @thelatemail!  I hadn't thought of using negative indexing--I have only used negative indexing once before, and it was a much more intuitive use of it in that former instance (at least it was for me).  Alex (above) also mentioned negative indexing too.  Thanks--much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Create a duplicate of column C6 and call it dupC6. Then run your code which makes everything 0. Next swap the values of dupC6 with C6. Im sure there are better ways however.

```
dupC6<-df$C6
df[df$C6 == "Y",] = 0 
df$C6<-dupC6
```

Comment: Thanks, @MaxPD!  I actually did try this out earlier when I was working things out in R myself.  But I found that this actually doesn't solve the problem for me--the duplicate C6 column also gets changed by the conditional rule I set, so the same problem persists.  Thanks so much for your input!